# Adding count down timer in html email body

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

How to add a dynamic timer in email body? basically by adding it in an html body?

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. That said: You cannot add any script in an email

Answer (score 3):

Countdown timers are GIF images that are sent from a server with the correct time.

You can either use a number of available solutions, as BADZY said - sendtric.com - but there is also:

https://www.sendtric.com/

https://www.liveclicker.com/

https://niftyimages.com/

https://movableink.com/

https://www.kickdynamic.com/

There is also a few github repos with email countdown timers you can edit and host on your own servers.

Jay

Comment: i would like to add the counter command with html code, the code that i am saving in a notepad and consuming later

Comment: You can create a countdown using CSS - the only problem is there is no way to reference the users time, as you can't use javascript etc. within the email.

Comment: can u send me that code without java and only css , will it work on outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you... And it's free.

https://www.sendtric.com/

Comment: i would like to add the counter command with html code, the code that i am saving in a notepad and consuming later